# Unable to select Dynamic Web Module Version 3.1 when using Jetty as the target runtime in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jetty, jetty-9

Disclaimer: I am new at servlet development, but have had years of Java experience.

The option for "3.1" becomes unavailable as the *Dynamic web module version* in Eclipse, when creating a new *Dynamic Web Project* while using Jetty as the *Target runtime*:

[image]

[image]

Choosing a runtime of "None" allows the selection of the 3.1 version, but this will not include the servlet libraries needed in the project:

[image]

The Jetty runtime is configured as such:

[image]

I am using the latest version of Jetty as of the time of writing (9.3.8).

I am using the latest version of Eclipse Java EE IDE as of the time of writing (4.5.2).

I am using the latest version of JDK 8 (8u74) as of the time of writing.

What have I configured wrong? I'd like to use Servlet 3.1 which Jetty should have supported since 9.1 according to their [documentation](https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-javaee.html).

Am I even approaching this the right way? As mentioned at the start, I am new in servlet development, but experienced in Java in general.

I have a hunch that perhaps I should *not* be using Eclipse's Dynamic Web Project wizard. If this is the case, then based on best practices for this scenario, what type of project should I be using instead and how do I configure it?

Comment: Did you try to use an specific plugin to jetty? Like [this](https://github.com/eclipse-jetty/eclipse-jetty-plugin)?

Comment: I have looked at that plugin a few days ago but have come to the conclusion that this is for launching a project (for running or debugging) once the said project has been set-up already. I have not gotten past the first step --- how to set-up the project.

Comment: Do you get some specific error on eclipse Erro Log view?

Comment: If I proceed using the "None" runtime in order for me to be able to use *Dynamic web module version* 3.1 then any Java program referencing javax.servlet will fail to compile (as the runtime is not specified). For example, an `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` will yield `HttpServlet cannot be resolved to a type` which I fully expect as I did choose no runtime.

Comment: Interesting, I checked my local projects and I noticed that I'm not using Dynamic web module, because I'm using as maven project. Anyway, try to put manullay your jetty reference in Build Path. Let me know you are aware how to do it.

Comment: I see. Would you have a link or would you be able to provide steps on how to set it up as a maven project? I have not used maven before, but this is something I'd like to try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106811/discussion-between-josivan-and-paul).